# Relationship between radio transmitter output power and its input electrical power?

Tags: power, rf, radio, transmitter

Given a radio station of a given licensed effective radiated power, is it the case that the transmitter requires at least that much mains power to run it? E.g., if a radio station says it's 100,000 watts, mustn't the transmitter take at least that much electrical power to operate?

Answer (score 2):

The efficiency of typical RF trasmitter is between 20...30% for AM transmitters, and 40...70% for FM transmiters. It means, the transmitter expects on main power 2...4x greater than output power.

For your example, 100,000W = 100kW on RF output means needs about 200...400kW of mains.

Answer (score 1):

Often the quoted transmitter power is the Effective Radiated Power (or ERP). This includes the gain of the antenna which can be high if the intention is to beam the signal in a specific direction.

As Tim states in the comments, this means that a lower transmit power is actually required for a given signal at the receiver; this may seem to result in apparently more than 100% efficiency for power into the transmitter to ERP.

The actual efficiency of the transmitter will, as you expect, be much less than 100% for the power delivered to the antenna.

Comment: In asking I was trying to suss out if there were anything about how ERP is specified that breaks the basic conservation-of-energy concept of power out being less than power in. I realize the antenna design and its resulting radiation pattern determines how much of the ERP is received at a point within the pattern.

Comment: "This includes the gain of the antenna which can be high".  This, in turn, means that the ERP can be higher (or lower, if the antenna has low gain) than the actual power applied to the antenna.  **That**, in turn, means that the ERP can be higher than the power used by the transmitter.

Comment: The "E" in ERP means "effective", and it's effective *in the direction of highest gain* ([see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_radiated_power)).  So ERP has a loose relation to actual radiated power -- much less RF power applied to the antenna, or power applied to the transmitter.

Comment: @TimWescott - All this being said, given an ERP value what can I estimate about the transmitter power consumption? Assume omnidirectional FM tower.

Comment: At the 100kW broadcast ERP level, there’s no such thing as a omnidirectional FM tower. Anybody building such a system would direct power in the plane of the Earth, I.e. to customers, not down into the earth or up into space. So the ERP will typically be 3-6 times the antenna input power.

Comment: "omnidirectional" antennas are not isotropic,  they mostly radiate parrallel to the ground. Gains of 3 dB or more are common. (and for FM  beamforming techniques like phased arrays will usually be used, because the wavelength is small compared to the size of the tower.

Comment: @BobJacobsen - I should have said "non-directional," which is the term FCC uses. I assumed any FM broadcast antenna isn't truly omnidirectional in elevation.